# creating an image format with an unknown type is an error. From Image selection from photolibrary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

App crashes after selecting image from the simulator's photo library with the error: "[Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error"

Comment: did u added didFinishPickingImage method? can u post that code?

Comment: - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
  
        UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}